# How to export the data of a contour plot from Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, export, color, column

I want to export the data of a contour plot that I made in Mathematica to graph it in another program. But when export the .dat, in which I want 3 columns to make the contour plot, it exports more than 11 columns. If I export only 2 columns, to make a 2D graph, I export it as below, and it works.

```
f[x_ ] := x + 1
fdata = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];
Export["C:\\Users\\hello\\Desktop\\Newfolder\\fdata_plotting.dat", fdata]
```

If I want to do it for a function of 2 variables for a contour plot, I tried to do it this way and it doesn't work. That is, it exports much more than 3 columns.

```
g[x_, y_] := x + y + 1
gdata = Table[{x, y, g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}, {y, 0, 5, 0.05}];
Export["C:\\Users\\hello\\Desktop\\Newfolder\\gdata_plotting.dat", gdata]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `gdata = Flatten[Table[{x, y, g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}, {y, 0, 5, 0.05}], 1]`